# twisted.pair.ethernet vs iptables

Tags: python, ethernet, iptables

I need to implement some low-level IP filtering/tracking.  Typically I would use iptables for this, but since I am currently using twisted in a few projects I'd consider using it's ethernet library, if it's possible.  Actually, I would prefer it (it's easier to deploy than iptables rules).

Is it possible to use twisted python's twisted.pair.ethernet to implement a partial analog of iptables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`twisted.pair.ethernet` will give you a little bit of the parsing, but it doesn't do anything for actually getting the data in the first place, nor putting it back on the network (if you don't filter it out).  For that you need to talk to the tuntap system, which Twisted doesn't do anything with.

Comment: Is there anything I can do with twisted.pair.tuntap + eunuch?